# Why does this image comparison crash my application?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple program that allows the user to select a reference image A and then get all images in the same directory, normalize them to the same size (300x300), extract the features, calculate the distance from the features of A and show them in order of less distant to most distant.

As a beginner in Java, I am having some trouble with the code, my code has no error, and I am able to run the program, however when I run the application, the application crashes, the console log is :

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream
    at javax.media.jai.operator.BMPDescriptor.class$(BMPDescriptor.java:95)
    at javax.media.jai.operator.BMPDescriptor.<clinit>(BMPDescriptor.java:94)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at javax.media.jai.RegistryFileParser.getInstance(RegistryFileParser.java:224)
    at javax.media.jai.RegistryFileParser.registerDescriptor(RegistryFileParser.java:360)
    at javax.media.jai.RegistryFileParser.parseFile(RegistryFileParser.java:295)
    at javax.media.jai.RegistryFileParser.loadOperationRegistry(RegistryFileParser.java:55)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.initializeRegistry(OperationRegistry.java:371)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.<clinit>(JAI.java:566)
    at imagePr.NaiveSimilarityFinder.rescale(NaiveSimilarityFinder.java:116)
    at imagePr.NaiveSimilarityFinder.<init>(NaiveSimilarityFinder.java:46)
    at imagePr.NaiveSimilarityFinder.main(NaiveSimilarityFinder.java:223)
```

Here is the Code of the Java file:

```
    9 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  10 import java.awt.Color;
  11 import java.awt.Container;
  12 import java.awt.Font;
  13 import java.awt.GridLayout;
  14 import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
  15 import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
  16 import java.io.File;
  17 import java.io.IOException;
  18  
  19 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  20 import javax.media.jai.InterpolationNearest; 
  21 import javax.media.jai.JAI;
  22 import javax.media.jai.iterator.RandomIter;
  23 import javax.media.jai.iterator.RandomIterFactory;
  24 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
  25 import javax.swing.JFrame;
  26 import javax.swing.JLabel;
  27 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  28 import javax.swing.JPanel;
  29 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  30  
  31 import com.sun.media.jai.widget.DisplayJAI;
  32 /**
  33  * This class uses a very simple, naive similarity algorithm to compare an image
  34  * with all others in the same directory.
  35  */
  36 public class NaiveSimilarityFinder extends JFrame
  37   {
  38   // The reference image "signature" (25 representative pixels, each in R,G,B).
  39   // We use instances of Color to make things simpler.
  40   private Color[][] signature;
  41   // The base size of the images.
  42   private static final int baseSize = 300;
  43   // Where are all the files?
  44   private static final String basePath = 
  45     "C:\\imagecmp";
  46   
  47  /*
  48   * The constructor, which creates the GUI and start the image processing task.
  49   */
  50   public NaiveSimilarityFinder(File reference) throws IOException
  51     {
  52     // Create the GUI
  53     super("Naive Similarity Finder");
  54     Container cp = getContentPane();
  55     cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  56     // Put the reference, scaled, in the left part of the UI.
  57     RenderedImage ref = rescale(ImageIO.read(reference));
  58     cp.add(new DisplayJAI(ref), BorderLayout.WEST);
  59     // Calculate the signature vector for the reference.
  60     signature = calcSignature(ref);
  61     // Now we need a component to store X images in a stack, where X is the
  62     // number of images in the same directory as the original one.
  63     File[] others = getOtherImageFiles(reference);
  64     JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(others.length, 2));
  65     cp.add(new JScrollPane(otherPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  66     // For each image, calculate its signature and its distance from the
  67     // reference signature.
  68     RenderedImage[] rothers = new RenderedImage[others.length];
  69     double[] distances = new double[others.length];
  70     for (int o = 0; o < others.length; o++)
  71       {
  72       rothers[o] = rescale(ImageIO.read(others[o]));
  73       distances[o] = calcDistance(rothers[o]);
  74       }
  75     // Sort those vectors *together*.
  76     for (int p1 = 0; p1 < others.length - 1; p1++)
  77       for (int p2 = p1 + 1; p2 < others.length; p2++)
  78         {
  79         if (distances[p1] > distances[p2])
  80           {
  81           double tempDist = distances[p1];
  82           distances[p1] = distances[p2];
  83           distances[p2] = tempDist;
  84           RenderedImage tempR = rothers[p1];
  85           rothers[p1] = rothers[p2];
  86           rothers[p2] = tempR;
  87           File tempF = others[p1];
  88           others[p1] = others[p2];
  89           others[p2] = tempF;
  90           }
  91         }
  92     // Add them to the UI.
  93     for (int o = 0; o < others.length; o++)
  94       {
  95       otherPanel.add(new DisplayJAI(rothers[o]));
  96       JLabel ldist = new JLabel("<html>" + others[o].getName() + "<br>"
  97           + String.format("% 13.3f", distances[o]) + "</html>");
  98       ldist.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 36));
  99       System.out.printf("<td class=\"simpletable legend\"> "+
 100           "<img src=\"MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_%s\" "+
 101           "alt=\"Similarity result\"><br>% 13.3f</td>\n", others[o].getName(),distances[o]);
 102       otherPanel.add(ldist);
 103       }
 104     // More GUI details.
 105     pack();
 106     setVisible(true);
 107     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 108     }
 109  
 110  /*
 111   * This method rescales an image to 300,300 pixels using the JAI scale
 112   * operator.
 113   */
 114   private RenderedImage rescale(RenderedImage i)
 115     {
 116     float scaleW = ((float) baseSize) / i.getWidth();
 117     float scaleH = ((float) baseSize) / i.getHeight();
 118     // Scales the original image
 119     ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
 120     pb.addSource(i);
 121     pb.add(scaleW);
 122     pb.add(scaleH);
 123     pb.add(0.0F);
 124     pb.add(0.0F);
 125     pb.add(new InterpolationNearest());
 126     // Creates a new, scaled image and uses it on the DisplayJAI component
 127     return JAI.create("scale", pb);
 128     }
 129   
 130  /*
 131   * This method calculates and returns signature vectors for the input image.
 132   */
 133   private Color[][] calcSignature(RenderedImage i)
 134     {
 135     // Get memory for the signature.
 136     Color[][] sig = new Color[5][5];
 137     // For each of the 25 signature values average the pixels around it.
 138     // Note that the coordinate of the central pixel is in proportions.
 139     float[] prop = new float[]
 140       {1f / 10f, 3f / 10f, 5f / 10f, 7f / 10f, 9f / 10f};
 141     for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
 142       for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
 143         sig[x][y] = averageAround(i, prop[x], prop[y]);
 144     return sig;
 145     }
 146  
 147  /*
 148   * This method averages the pixel values around a central point and return the
 149   * average as an instance of Color. The point coordinates are proportional to
 150   * the image.
 151   */
 152   private Color averageAround(RenderedImage i, double px, double py)
 153     {
 154     // Get an iterator for the image.
 155     RandomIter iterator = RandomIterFactory.create(i, null);
 156     // Get memory for a pixel and for the accumulator.
 157     double[] pixel = new double[3];
 158     double[] accum = new double[3];
 159     // The size of the sampling area.
 160     int sampleSize = 15;
 161     int numPixels = 0;
 162     // Sample the pixels.
 163     for (double x = px * baseSize - sampleSize; x < px * baseSize + sampleSize; x++)
 164       {
 165       for (double y = py * baseSize - sampleSize; y < py * baseSize + sampleSize; y++)
 166         {
 167         iterator.getPixel((int) x, (int) y, pixel);
 168         accum[0] += pixel[0];
 169         accum[1] += pixel[1];
 170         accum[2] += pixel[2];
 171         numPixels++;
 172         }
 173       }
 174     // Average the accumulated values.
 175     accum[0] /= numPixels;
 176     accum[1] /= numPixels;
 177     accum[2] /= numPixels;
 178     return new Color((int) accum[0], (int) accum[1], (int) accum[2]);
 179     }
 180  
 181  /*
 182   * This method calculates the distance between the signatures of an image and
 183   * the reference one. The signatures for the image passed as the parameter are
 184   * calculated inside the method.
 185   */
 186   private double calcDistance(RenderedImage other)
 187     {
 188     // Calculate the signature for that image.
 189     Color[][] sigOther = calcSignature(other);
 190     // There are several ways to calculate distances between two vectors,
 191     // we will calculate the sum of the distances between the RGB values of
 192     // pixels in the same positions.
 193     double dist = 0;
 194     for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
 195       for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
 196         {
 197         int r1 = signature[x][y].getRed();
 198         int g1 = signature[x][y].getGreen();
 199         int b1 = signature[x][y].getBlue();
 200         int r2 = sigOther[x][y].getRed();
 201         int g2 = sigOther[x][y].getGreen();
 202         int b2 = sigOther[x][y].getBlue();
 203         double tempDist = Math.sqrt((r1 - r2) * (r1 - r2) + (g1 - g2)
 204             * (g1 - g2) + (b1 - b2) * (b1 - b2));
 205         dist += tempDist;
 206         }
 207     return dist;
 208     }
 209  
 210  /*
 211   * This method get all image files in the same directory as the reference.
 212   * Just for kicks include also the reference image.
 213   */
 214   private File[] getOtherImageFiles(File reference)
 215     {
 216     File dir = new File(reference.getParent());
 217     // List all the image files in that directory.
 218     File[] others = dir.listFiles(new JPEGImageFileFilter());
 219     return others;
 220     }
 221  
 222  /*
 223   * The entry point for the application, which opens a file with an image that
 224   * will be used as reference and starts the application.
 225   */
 226   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 227     {
 228     JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(basePath);
 229     fc.setFileFilter(new JPEGImageFileFilter());
 230     int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
 231     // We have an image!
 232     if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
 233       {
 234       File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
 235       new NaiveSimilarityFinder(file);
 236       }
 237     // Oops!
 238     else
 239       {
 240       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
 241           "You must select one image to be the reference.", "Aborting...",
 242           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 243       }
 244     }
 245   
 246   }
```

Any quick guess where I might be doing wrong? I am coding in Eclipse in a Windows machine.

Comment: IIRC JAI needs to be installed into the JVM so it might not be present when you try to run your application.

Comment: Any link to know what it is and how to install that :(

Comment: Try the Sun/Oracle JVM instead for this Sun codec.

Comment: Oracle's documentation on JAI seems to be somewhat outdated or even confusing (links not working etc.) but it seems that JAI has been moved to java.net so have a look here: https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio

Comment: "The JAI project is no longer active and many of the JARs can't be found in public Maven repositories, so if you have a choice, you could consider using a more active project such as Apache Commons Imaging." found this answer in a similar question ? How true does that goes ? Also,  The links to jai in oracle , gives a 404 error, Do I need to install the latest one ?

Comment: I have the same impression, i.e. that JAI seems to be inactive or at least the documentation seems outdated etc. We're using Apache Commons Imaging for some use cases but when you need to support more codecs and/or higher performance you could add native libraries like Image Magick using a wrapper like im4java (that's what we're doing and what replaced Apache Commons Imaging and built in Java imaging in most projects).

Comment: Do you find any link to download the IIRC JAI for jvm ?

Comment: JAI is indeed abandoned. You can get the jars from the central Maven repository. I'm not exactly sure which jars you specifically need, one or more might be redundant. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.media/jai_core/1.1.3, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.media/jai_imageio/1.1 and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.media/jai_codec/1.1.2_01

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if anybody is still interested in this question, but I was curious about it and tried to find the source of your code in question. It seems to originate from here: [Java Image Processing Cookbook](http://web.archive.org/web/20160716062247/http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp)

To test the code I just setup a simple Maven-based Java project and of course ran into the problem, that there is no Java Media Framework in Java 11 anymore! ;-)

So I added this nice Springsource dependency to my project pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To reach the springsource repository I added this repository information as well:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After doing that the project was successfully compilable and runs as intended. It calculates a very simple similarity-index between a selected image (file selector opens when running) and all other images in the same directory.

Yet, there is a minor drawback, because there seems to be a problem with finding a missing mediaLib accelerator to speed up processing. It looks like this:

```
Error: Could not find mediaLib accelerator wrapper classes. Continuing in pure Java mode.
Occurs in: com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/medialib/mlib/Image
    at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor$1.run(MediaLibAccessor.java:248)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
[...]
```

Fortunately the calculations run still very quickly and the results are quite interesting ;-) What a nice little piece if basic Java Imaging code for a very basic similarity comparison of images! Well done! :)

**UPDATE**: to get rid of the errors concerning missing accelerators, please change this environment variable by adding this to your code:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib", "true");
```

See here for a sample output of my used images. To understand the values see [Java Image Processing Cookbook](http://web.archive.org/web/20160716062247/http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp) as well:

```
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_action-ancient-architecture-231013.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>        0,000</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_army-blur-figurines-231014.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     2169,529</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_action-armed-army-231012.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     2525,682</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_army-attack-figurines-1214270.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     2610,023</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_bowl-cereal-bowl-cereals-135525.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     3388,865</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_blue-bowl-bright-1375811.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     3392,382</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_aqua-blue-clean-1201625.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     4121,866</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_background-berries-blue-674689.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     4133,818</td>
<td class="simpletable legend"> <img src="MiscResources/ImageSimilarity/icons/miniicon_blue-bright-citrus-405031.jpg" alt="Similarity result"><br>     4746,385</td>
```

---